# How to show a user as logged in between Wordpress and MVC site

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a web tier that splits our "portal" and our public facing website.  The public website is hosted in a linux environment in wordpress at `xx.com`.  The portal is an MVC app hosted in Azure on `sub1.xx.com` using SimpleMembership/Forms Authentication.

Users currently log in to the portal, and user information is displayed in the header.  If they navigate back to the public side of the website, that information is not present because they are two separate systems.

What is the best practice for reconciling this?

Is there a way to wire the wordpress site in, or perhaps I should simply iframe in a small control  on the public site that's hosted on the portal site and displays either the login controls, or their user information?

Comment: I can only hope to get started in the right direction. SimpleMembership/Forms Authentication is really tough to work with if you need a solution to be flexible. The ASP.net Membership Provider is 100% new in MVC5. It uses Facebook and Google OAuth2 and OpenID Sign.

I'm not sure if the RESPONSE sent from OpenID can authenticate more than one site. That would be the first thing I would look into. 

Alternatively, research Amazon Virtual Private Cloud Amazon VPC.
Hope that helps.

http://www.asp.net/identity
http://openid.net/
http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/